# Lambda function returning auto like behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm having problems trying to create the following lambda function:

```
const auto var x = [&y]() -> /*???*/ {
if (y == type1) {
  return some_type_1;
} else if (y == type2) {
  return some_type_2;
} else // ...
```

I know I cannot use auto as return type. But how can I do it in another way?

Thanks!

Comment: How would you do it with a regular, non-lambda, function? What do all those types have in common?

Comment: They are some kind of string implemented from a common interface, but I don't want to use polymorphism, I want to return that specific type.

Comment: You cannot return a type that is determined at runtime. There is no way around that so don't even think of trying it. (It will only work if you end up using polymorphism)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `some_type_1` and `some_type_2` have a common type, write:

```
const auto var x = [&y]() -> typename std::common_type<
  decltype(some_type_1),
  decltype(some_type_2)>::type {
if (y == type1) {
  return some_type_1;
} else if (y == type2) {
  return some_type_2;
} else // ...
```

Equivalently, you can use a ternary expression:

```
const auto var x = [&y]() {
  (y == type1) ? some_type_1 :
  (y == type2) ? some_type_2 :
  ...;
}
```

Comment: I can't use decltype. I'm using vs 2010

Comment: Then you can use decltype.